# How to deactivate local accounts using AD?

Tags: active-directory

I want to disable the local users accounts on the machines that are in the domain?
i tried to deactivate it from "Configuration \ Windows Settings \ Security Settings \ Local Policies \ User Rights Assignment" but doesn't seem to be working\; I still can logon with a local account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it directly from AD, but you can script and distribute via GPO.

[This is a script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/47ad1824-5af7-451e-a9f5-f6dd90421394) that should do something like what you want, but BEWARE: this script as written disables everything that isn't Administrator or ASPNET.  Modify and test before deploying.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly from AD.

In the `Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment` you can find a following option: `Allow log on locally`.

Enable this policy and enter following account on the list: `MyDomain\Authenticated Users` and `BUILTIN\Administrator` (the latter will keep you able to login using built-in administrative account).

This way, only domain-authenticated users will be able to log-on locally (that is, perform interactive logon using logon screen).